# manipulating the url from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the url where I am getting lost. What is the issue?

I am getting the value as:

```
mydomain.mymaindomain.com/http://mydomain.mymaindomain.com/asppage.asp?paramsgoes---
```

But sometimes it comes as:

```
http://mydomain.mymaindomain.com/asppage.asp?paramsgoes---
```

So I want to make sure that if the `mydomain.mymaindomain.com/` comes extra, I want jquery to try to remove it. I am lost as to where I try to do it.

It is not showing `http://` but it could be applying or it could not be applying, I'm not sure at this point.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase your question? I'm not getting what you want to achieve at all. :)

Comment: Please clarify - *It is not showing http:// but it could be applying or it could not be applying, I'm not sure at this point*

Comment: what i am trying to check is if the mydomain.mymaindomain.com/ is being added to the url, i should remove it, if not, it should not do anything

Comment: Where is this appearing? Can you show the code that's getting the extra part?

Comment: u read my qyestion, the url is formed with that

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to check whether the last occurrence of `http` is at the beginning of the string or somewhere in the middle. There's no need for jQuery, this is vanilla JS:

```
str = 'http://somedomain';
var pos = str.lastIndexOf('http');
if (0 != pos) {
    str = str.substring(pos);
}
```

This will return `http://mydomain.mymaindomain.com/asppage.asp?` for:

```
http://mydomain.mymaindomain.com/asppage.asp?
http://mydomain.mymaindomain.com/http://mydomain.mymaindomain.com/asppage.asp
mydomain.mymaindomain.com/http://mydomain.mymaindomain.com/asppage.asp
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/k8jpoLje/)